# error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Tags: git, github, repository, git-push

The `git push` command is not working for me.

First I tried `$ git push -u origin master`:

```
Enumerating objects: 416, done.
Counting objects: 100% (416/416), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (214/214), done.
Writing objects: 100% (416/416), 36.52 MiB | 159.14 MiB/s, done.
Total 416 (delta 200), reused 416 (delta 200), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I tried `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`:

```
  $ git status
  On branch master
  nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Why can't I get `git push` to work?

Comment: I can not push to github because of this error please help me as soon as you can

Comment: You [should not use `http.postBuffer` unless you're sure you need it](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-WhatdoescodehttppostBuffercodereallydo), since it wastes a lot of memory.

Comment: Also, what operating system are you on?  Do you have a third-party firewall or antivirus?  Are you using a proxy or SSL MITM device on your network?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the Git buffer size to the largest individual file size of your repo:

git config --global http.postBuffer